# Changes page with Class on Viewpager

Tags: android, class, pager, android-viewpager

friends.
I'm trying to make ViewPager to my applications. I've made pager function to show page and slide to change a page.
But, on my Main Activity (NUM_PAGES = 3), i want to set my every Class : Class One, Two, and Three to the pageView, is it possible?

Here is my source :

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       scroller = ((Pager)findViewById(R.id.scrollView));
       indicator = ((PageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator));
       indicator.setPager(scroller);

       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

       for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {
        .....
        what should i do here?
        .....

        scroller.addPage(pageView);
    }
```

So, if i slide it to right side, it will change to Class "Two" (page 2), and if i slide it to right again, it will cange to Class "Three" (page 3).

Help me please, Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused with the R.id.scrollview being cast to a pager, but I can offer some advice.

It looks like you are taking a odd approach. I'm not entirely sure what the Pager object is to be honest. You might be using a 3rd party non-sdk/non-google code. I'll do my best to explain how you would do this with the SDK and compatibility library.

What you probably want is a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.

The ViewPager is the View that does the paging. The Adapter is a interface that works with the view and tells it what to show on each page.

1) Integrate the ViewPager in your XML

2) Implement a PagerAdapter, which is where all that "what should I do here" logic will go.

The adapter will be called when the view needs something to display. It's similar to ListViews and other AdapterViews in the android system.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Comment: no, i mean, it's i've found it when googling it. But, it just used for view and not an activites :(